# ReduceStore is not working. Render not being called

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am using flux reducestore and it does not appear to be working. If I change the application state the view is *not* updating, and the render method is *not* being called.

I am simply rendering my application like so :

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <AppContainer/>
  </div>
  , app);
```

Which is rendering a Component (*a flux container*) and is just showing a textfield and some text from the application state. The state value is found here : **this.state.app.name**

My application view :

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import {Container} from 'flux/utils';
import AppStore from './AppStore.js';

import dispatcher from "./AppDispatcher.js";

class AppContainer extends Component {

  static getStores() {
    return [AppStore];
  }

  static calculateState(prevState) {
    return AppStore.getState();
  }

  changeText(event) {
    var changeName = function(newName) {
      dispatcher.dispatch({
        type: "CHANGE_NAME",
        newName,
      });
    }
    changeName(event.currentTarget.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.app.name}</div>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.changeText}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Container.create(AppContainer);
```

The **this.state.app.name** is found in the state object here :

State :

```
const AppState =
  {
    app: {
        name: "i want to change",
    }
  }
export default AppState;
```

The store is a flux store

Store :

```
import {ReduceStore} from "flux/utils";

import AppState from "./AppState.js";
import AppDispatcher from "./AppDispatcher.js";

class AppStore extends ReduceStore {
  constructor() {
    super(AppDispatcher);
  }

  getInitialState() {
    var state = AppState;
    return state;
  }

  reduce(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'CHANGE_NAME':
        var newName = action.newName;
        state.app.name = newName;
        break;
    }
    return state;
  }
}

export default new AppStore();
```

Everything looks good as far as I can tell, but the component is not rendering. If I change text in the textfield, then the action is triggered and the reduce method is called. The line **"state.app.name = newName"** is called, however the 'render' method is not called in my view!

It says when using the ReduceStore that you shouldn't use **setState(..)**, you simply need to change the state object and you are fine, but it doesn't seem to work for me. There is also no 'emitChange' method that needs to be called.

I'm stumped everything seems to be fine, but the render is not being triggered for me :/

Sorry to bombard with all this code, but i can't find a fiddle-esque website which can show me all the files I need. Ideally i would like to show this in a live link.

Comment: UPDATE : looking at the flux code it looks like I shouldn't be modifying the state object. It should be immutable.

Comment: UPDATE 2 : Ok this is seriously a NEVER.ENDING.PAIN . I have tried to use Immutable, but now the reducer is stripping out my immutable methods from my immutable state object. Thinking of dumping flux. There are no patterns or documentation how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, it appears that you have to return a new object, not a modification of the `state` that is passed into the render function, for `emit` and `render` methods to be called.

So I would make the following changes...

```
getInitialState() {
    return AppState;
}

reduce(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'CHANGE_NAME':

      var newName = action.newName;
      var newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      newState.name = newName;  
      return newState;

    default:

      return state;

  }
}
```